# Undefined reference usando clases en C++

Tags: c++, diseño-de-clases

estoy aprendiendo a usar clases en C++.
Cuando quiero crear una clase TRIANGULO con un Constructor sin parametros.
Una funcion llamada Crear() me permita ingresar los datos.
Otra funcion llamada Mostrar() me permita ver los datos ingresados.
Otra funcion llamada Area() me permita calcular el area con los datos ingresados.
Otra funcion llamada Mover() me permita modificar los valores de coordenada de la posicion
y luego usar Mostrar() para ver la nuevas nuevas coordenadas.
El único error que me marca al compilar me sale "Undefined Reference to TRIANGULO::TRIANGULO(), error: Id returned 1 exit status

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Este es el código:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;


class TRIANGULO{

private:
int base, altura, area, x, y;

public:
TRIANGULO(); //Constructor sin parametros
//protipos de las funciones
void Crear();
void Mostrar();
void Area();
void Mover();
};

int main(){

TRIANGULO T1; //Objeto de la clase
T1.Crear();
T1.Mostrar(); //Mostrar datos del objeto creado
T1.Area();
T1.Mover();
T1.Mostrar(); //Mostrar nuevas coordenadas

return 0;
}

//Definicion de las funciones 
void TRIANGULO::Crear(){
cout<<"Pos en X:";
cin>>x;
cout<<"Pos en Y";
cin>>y;

cout<<"Base: ";
cin>>base;
cout<<"Altura: ";
cin>>altura;
}

void TRIANGULO::Mostrar(){
cout<<"*Posicion*"<<endl;
cout<<"("<<x<<","<<y<<")";
cout<<"*Datos*"<<endl;
cout<<base;
cout<<altura;
}

void TRIANGULO::Area(){
cout<<"Calculando Area"<<endl;
area = (base*altura)/2;
cout<<"El area es: "<<area<<endl;

}

void TRIANGULO::Mover(){
cout<<"Ingrese las nuevas coordenadas del triangulo"<<endl;
cout<<"Pos en X:";
cin>>x;
cout<<"Pos en Y";
cin>>y;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Has declarado el constructor de `TRIANGULO`:

```
class TRIANGULO{

private:
int base, altura, area, x, y;

public:
TRIANGULO(); // Constructor DECLARADO
...
};
```

Pero no lo has definido, añade esto a tu código:

1. Primera opción, que el compilador cree el constructor:

   ```
   class TRIANGULO{

   private:
   // Dar valor inicial a las variables miembro.
   int base = 0, altura = 0, area = 0, x = 0, y = 0;

   public:
   TRIANGULO() = default; // El compilador creará el constructor
   //protipos de las funciones
   void Crear();
   void Mostrar();
   void Area();
   void Mover();
   };
   ```
2. Segunda opción, crea tú el constructor añadiendo esto:

   ```
   TRIANGULO::TRIANGULO() {}
   ```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Ya resultó. Por último, si quiero destruir el objeto, basta con usar un destructor?

Comment: El destructor no es para destruir un objeto, es para si se necesita hacer hacer algo cuando el objeto se va a destruir (que no es tu caso). Los objetos se destruyen solos al salir del ámbito en que se crearon (si están en memoria automática).